# How to change SESSION_CACHED_CURSORS for all sessions

Tags: oracle, session, environment-variables

how Can I do to change SESSION_CACHED_CURSORS for all sessions?

I found on google and oracle website:

`Alter Session...` but I need to changed it for all the session and not only for one of them.

How can I do it?

UPDATE 1:

```
SQL> alter session set session_cached_cursors=800 scope=both sid='*';
alter session set session_cached_cursors=800 scope=both sid='*'
                                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02248: invalid option for ALTER SESSION
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ALTER SYSTEM SET clause for this parameter is only valid with the SCOPE=SPFILE option, so you can not change the parameter value with this dynamically.

You can change the value for all other sessions, e.g as below:

```
begin
for c in (select sid, serial# from v$session) loop
   dbms_system.set_int_param_in_session(c.sid,c.serial#,'session_cached_cursors', 100);
end loop;
end;
/
```

This however will not have any effect on the sessions opened after this point.
For that, you have to use ALTER SYSTEM as above and restart the database.

Comment: THANKs, it worked with the scope option, but I added sid='*' because I needed it for all the instances

Answer (score -1):

Please use

```
alter system set session_cached_cursors=800 scope=spfile;
```

Comment: please always add some explanation, what you are doing and why, so that others can find it easier